# CS0103: The name 'EmailCollections' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net

I copied over an old form and created this new one with different fields and am now getting the following error message.

\www\assets\root\forms\revenueanalysis.aspx.cs(50,13): error CS0103: The name 'EmailCollections' does not exist in the current context

\www\assets\root\forms\revenueanalysis.aspx.cs(61,18): error CS0103: The name 'Utility' does not exist in the current context

\www\assets\root\forms\revenueanalysis.aspx.cs(74,18): error CS0103: The name 'Utility' does not exist in the current context

```
        using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Web.Mail;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

public partial class revenueanalysis : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsFormValid())
    {
        string name = string.Empty;
        string emailAddress = string.Empty;
        string emailAddress2 = string.Empty;
        string phone = string.Empty;
        string title = string.Empty;
        string company = string.Empty;
        string comment = string.Empty;
        string specialties = string.Empty;      
        string cases = string.Empty;


        name = tbName.Text;
        emailAddress = tbEmail.Text;
        emailAddress2 = tbEmail2.Text;
        phone = tbPhone.Text;
        title = tbTitle.Text;
        company = tbCompany.Text;
        comment = tbComment.Text;
        specialties = tbSpecialties.Text;
        cases = tbCases.Text;


        EmailCollections.SendNewrevenueanalysisFormEmail(name, emailAddress, emailAddress2, phone, title, company, comment, specialties,  cases,  this);
    }
}

private bool IsFormValid()
{
    bool isvalid = true;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbName.Text)) { isvalid = false; lblName.CssClass = "error"; } else { lblName.CssClass = ""; }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbEmail.Text)) { isvalid = false; lblEmail.CssClass = "error"; }
    else
    {
        if (!Utility.IsEmailValid(tbEmail.Text))
        {
            isvalid = false;
            lblEmail.CssClass = "error";
        }
        else
        {
            lblEmail.CssClass = "";
        }
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbEmail2.Text)) { isvalid = false; lblEmail.CssClass = "error"; }
    else
    {
        if (!Utility.IsEmailValid(tbEmail2.Text))
        {
            isvalid = false;
            lblEmail.CssClass = "error";
        }
        else
        {
            lblEmail.CssClass = "";
        }
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbPhone.Text)) { isvalid = false; lblPhone.CssClass = "error"; } else { tbPhone.CssClass = ""; }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbTitle.Text)) { isvalid = false; lblTitle.CssClass = "error"; } else { tbTitle.CssClass = ""; }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbCompany.Text)) { isvalid = false; lblCompany.CssClass = "error"; } else { tbCompany.CssClass = ""; }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbComment.Text)) { isvalid = false; lblComment.CssClass = "error"; } else { tbComment.CssClass = ""; }


    return isvalid;
}
}
```

-----Update-----
This is the code that I copied over, it looks like all the 'using' statements are the same. And this form is functioning like normal.

```
                                        using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Web.Mail;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

public partial class RequestProposal : System.Web.UI.Page
{ 
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

    }
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsFormValid())
        {
            string name = string.Empty;
            string emailAddress = string.Empty;
string phone = string.Empty;
            string message = string.Empty;
            string cases = string.Empty;
            string specialties = string.Empty;
            string nOperatingR = string.Empty;
            string nProcedureR = string.Empty;
            string state = string.Empty;

            name = tbName.Text;
            emailAddress = tbEmail.Text;
phone = tbPhone.Text;
            message = tbComment.Text;
            cases = tbCases.Text;
            specialties = tbSpecialties.Text;
            nOperatingR = tbOperatingR.Text;
            nProcedureR = tbProcedureR.Text;
            state = tbState.Text;

            EmailCollections.SendNewRequestProposalFormEmail(name, emailAddress, phone, message, cases, specialties,  nOperatingR, nProcedureR, state,  this);
        }
    }

    private bool IsFormValid()
    {
        bool isvalid = true;
         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbName.Text)) { isvalid = false; lblName.CssClass = "error"; } else { lblName.CssClass = ""; }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbEmail.Text)) { isvalid = false; lblEmail.CssClass = "error"; }
        else
         {
            if (!Utility.IsEmailValid(tbEmail.Text))
            {
                 isvalid = false;
                lblEmail.CssClass = "error";
             }
            else
            {
                lblEmail.CssClass = "";
            }
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbComment.Text)) { isvalid = false; lblComment.CssClass = "error"; } else { tbComment.CssClass = ""; }

        return isvalid;
    }
}
```

Comment: The page you copied seems to be a `partial` -- are you sure that you also copied the other portions?

Comment: Yep, you don't seem to include or construct either email collections or utility

Comment: I apologize, I had this site dumped on me and am not familiar with c#. The other 2 forms that use this same code (the emailcollections and utility) still work fine, would I be needing to define 'revenueanalysis' somewhere?

Comment: I would do a 'global find' in the project/solution looking for the original name of the form you copied, maybe using this as the search string: `public partial class WhatEverTheOriginalFormWasNamed` -- you should be able to find more than place that the original form was declared.  You are missing one of them.

Comment: David, sadly is hosted with a cms and I don't have that feature. I've tried to manually go through the files and see if I can find where the original form was declared and can't find any places I am missing. (but obviously am)

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to access an object "EmailCollections" at the end of your btnSubmit_Click method:

```
EmailCollections.SendNewrevenueanalysisFormEmail(name, emailAddress, emailAddress2, phone, title, company, comment, specialties,  cases,  this);
```

You are also attempting to access a "Utility" object in multiple places:

```
if (!Utility.IsEmailValid(tbEmail.Text))
```

The error you are receiving is because the system doesn't know where to find those objects.  Is it possible that when you copied over the old for, you lost some of the "using" statements at the top which pointed to the missing objects' namespaces?  If you still have the old copy, I would suggest checking the "using" statements and including the ones which contain the missing object definitions.

Comment: I added the code I copied over in the OP it all looks to be the same.

Comment: You may want to check that the new project isn't missing any of the required references from the old project as well.  Also, as others have mentioned, this is a partial class, so you may want to search the project to see where else the class is being defined, if anywhere, and see if there's any missing "using" statements there.